# Efficiently resolving belongs_to relationship in elixir dataloader?

Tags: graphql, elixir, dataloader, absinthe

Is it possible to use elixir dataloader to query a `belongs_to` relationship efficiently? It seems that the `load` is querying all of the items it needs, but the `get` is returning the first value of the loaded items regardless of which single item it actually needs. This is the code that I am using now:

```
field :node, :node_object, resolve: fn parent, _, %{context: %{loader: loader}} ->
  # parent.node_id = 1, but concurrently also another parent.node_id = 5
  loader
  |> Dataloader.load(NodeContext, :node, parent) # loads node_id 5 and 1
  |> on_load(fn loader ->
    loader
    |> Dataloader.get(NodeContext, :node, parent) # always returns the node with id = 5
    |> (&{:ok, &1}).()
  end)                                                     
end
```

My current work around is to use the following code, but it makes the code much uglier and unfriendly with the Ecto schemas since I need to explicitly specify the node schema and node_id field of the parent schema here instead of letting dataloader infer it from the existing ecto schemas:

```
field :node, :node_object, resolve: fn parent, _, %{context: %{loader: loader}} ->
  loader
  |> Dataloader.load(NodeContext, {:one, NodeSchema}, id: parent.node_id)
  |> on_load(fn loader ->
    loader
    |> Dataloader.get(NodeContext, {:one, NodeSchema}, id: parent.node_id)
    |> (&{:ok, &1}).()
  end)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by making the `node_id` a `primary_key` of the parent schema like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.ParentSchema do
  use Ecto.Schema
  alias MyApp.NodeSchema

  @primary_key false

  embedded_schema do
    belongs_to :node, NodeSchema, primary_key: true
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if this is intended behavior for the `dataloader` since it seems like the `primary_key` check should happen on the child object instead of the parent object.

Comment: Please, do not forget to mark this answer as correct when allowed.